# Android Shared Preferences Updating

Tags: java, android

I have two projects/packages part of the same application.  The main project of the application does virtually everything on the app.  However, we used a 2nd project to manage updates to the application.  We are using shared preferences that are updated from the sqlite3 database and applied in the main application using

```
    editor.putString("string", sString).apply();
```

We also use the following logic to see if its a new version and if so restart the autoupdate package

```
    if (!sCurrentVersion.equals(ver)) {
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
        intent1 = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.pack.autoupdate");
        intent1.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        startActivity(intent1);
    }
```

Then in the autoupdate package, we simply just use getSharedPreferences().  The values we need in the shared preferences are the update urls that the autoupdate package needs to check.

Our problem is that we updated those urls in the database, however we are still getting some devices that are using the old urls in the autoupdate check.  Do I need to make sure and restart autoupdate or is there something i'm doing wrong with sharedpreferences?

Comment: Have you tried using a shared preferences listener?  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener.html

Comment: thanks logray, how is this different then using
              `getSharedPreferences("SharedPrefs",Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);`

Comment: getSharedPreferences works one time.  Add a listener and anytime a preference changes (for example in one class), you can process whatever you like, for example to affect another app/class.  That way you don't have to manually update your prefs, just let the listener take care of it.  From the docs a shared pref listener is "called when a shared preference is changed, added, or removed. This may be called even if a preference is set to its existing value."

Comment: thanks again logray that makes sense.
i have my getsharedpreferences in a receiver that gets called every 5 minutes.  Do you think its just retrieving the same value over and over again, and the device/application would need a restart to get the latest values for those shared preferences?

Comment: I am using editor.clear() before all the applys, wonder if that makes a difference

Comment: if you want to clear your prefs (wipe them) you should clear, then commit, then apply/commit new prefs.  Also a listener is superior to doing something every 5 minutes, because it only works when a pref is changed, doing something every 5 minutes drains battery.

Comment: well the receiver is scheduled to check if there is an update every 5 minutes which is why I need to call the getsharedpreferences to get the update url also every 5 minutes.  thanks so much for your help, I will implement it and see what happens!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you do call the .commit() method to update your SharedPreference value?

**Update :**

More information regarding the difference between .commit() and .apply() [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#apply%28%29)

Comment: no i ended it with
`editor.apply();` I'll have to lookup what the difference is on those, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: There is a distinction between .apply() and .commit() : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#apply%28%29

Comment: well im doing the following:  
`editor.putString("SoftwareName", sSoftwareName).apply();
  editor.putString("SoftwareUpdateVersionCheck",
    sSoftwareUpdateVersionCheck).apply();
  editor.putString("SoftwareUpdateURL", sSoftwareUpdateURL).apply();
editor.apply();`

from reading that documentation it seems like apply is the way to go but i'm not sure if im locking myself out with that many apply methods...

Comment: @user1288686 try starting with editor = prefs.edit();.  Then take out the .apply()'s on each change, then just do one editor.apply() at the end (or commit) like you have it there, also see my comment to yours below your question.